# How to redirect to a specific page according to a condition in React-Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, firebase-authentication, react-redux

How to redirect to a specific page according to a condition in `"react-router": "^4.0.0"`.

```
var { HashRouter, Route, Switch} = require('react-router-dom');
var {Provider}  = require('react-redux');
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user){
        this.props.history.push('/todos/');
      }else{
        this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    });


    store.dispatch(actions.startAddTodos());

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store = {store}>
        <div>
          <HashRouter>
            <div>
              <div className="columns medium-6 large-4 small-centered">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path='/todos' component={TodoApp}/>
                  <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
                  <Route component={Login}/>
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </HashRouter>
        </div>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

---

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

---

**EDIT :**

**The Application on Github:**
[React-Todo](https://github.com/MohammedNagar/react-todo)

Comment: add a condition inside TodoApp or Login components

Answer (score 8):

You can't use `this.props` because you are not inside of a component.

So to perform redirect you need to use the `Redirect` component from `react-router-dom`

I would recommend you create an HOC(High order component to take care of it.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import firebase from 'firebase'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return(
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => user
        ?(
          <Component />
        ) 
        :(
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}/>
        ) 
      )
 
      
    )}/>
  )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Then you only need to import PrivateRoute inside of your index.js file instead of using `Route` use `PrivateRoute` for the routes that require being authenticated.

```js
var { HashRouter, Route, Switch} = require('react-router-dom');
var PrivateRoute = require('./privateRoute')
var { Provider }  = require('react-redux');

    store.dispatch(actions.startAddTodos());

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store = {store}>
        <div>
          <HashRouter>
            <div>
              <div className="columns medium-6 large-4 small-centered">
                <Switch>
                  <PrivateRoute path='/todos' component={TodoApp}/>
                  <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
                  <Route component={Login}/>
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </HashRouter>
        </div>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but i get the following error : `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.`

Comment: I edited my answer, where I'm importing privateRoute,
before my edit was `var { PrivateRoute } = from ('./privateRoute')`, let me know if work now

Comment: i have already edited it to `import { PrivateRoute } from 'privateRoute';` but get the previous error

Comment: and I have to remove `const get` from the component because i get a syntax error when i try to webpack !

Comment: yes because is being exported by default that means that you have to import in this way `import PrivateRoute from './privateRoute'  ` without curly braces

Comment: Great the error has gone, but it doesn't redirect to my main component `TodoApp` after i successfully login

Comment: BTW I have removed `const get` because i get a syntax error when i try to webpack

Comment: even i try to redirect my self like this `http://localhost:3000/#/todos`, i get the following error : `Route.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: when i use `Route` instead of `PrivateRoute` and go to `http://localhost:3000/#/todos` i succeed to load the component without any error

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react router then it can be easier if you're maintaining user auth in your state.

```
  { /* Protect your routes you can include any no.of routes */ }
  <Route onEnter={requireLogin}>
    <Route path='/todos' component={TodoApp}/>
  </Route>
```

Next, write a small wrapper for requireLogin in which you check the auth state and do redirection inside it. It looks something like this

```
const requireLogin = (nextState, replace, cb) => {
            function checkAuth() {
             const user = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => user); // check login in your state
              if (!user) {
                replace('/'); // make user to redirect to some route based on your requirement
              }
              cb(); //if user present in it fallback to here
            }
    };
```