# Route.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I get the following errors although i return one root element :

> Route.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You
>   may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

---

> dispatch is not a function

---

My Code :

```
export var PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user) {
        console.log('ON...ON');
        var {dispatch} = props;
        dispatch(actions.login(user.uid));
        dispatch(actions.startAddTodos());
        return(
          <Component  {...props} />
        ) ;

      } else {
        console.log('OFF...OFF');

        dispatch(actions.logout());

        return (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        );

      }
    });
  }} />);
}
export default Redux.connect()(PrivateRoute);
```

---

[Github Link](https://github.com/MohammedNagar/react-todo)

Comment: Your return is inside async callback and not a direct return to the function that is taking `props` as argument

Comment: @MohammadElbanna : Thanks, Could you suggest a solution to the problem, please

Comment: I posted a suggestion to fix that. Hope it works!

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is that your are returning UI inside an async function.

I think your component should have a state `isLoading` to show the user something until the authentication operation finishes.
When `isLoading` is true you should show a loading indicator
else you should show your other components that are related to the auth success or failure.

You should also define a state for auth success or failure.

***Note***: I'm going to use react component state system instead of Redux because I don't know much about your redux state tree. Feel free to try to convert that to Redux

First thing you should refactor the component that you're going to route to in a separate class component. let's call that
component `UserAuth`

```
class UserAuth extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true
    isUserAuth: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user) {
        this.setState({isLoading: false, isUserAuth: true})
        // the rest of your logic here
      }
      else {
        this.setState({isLoading: false, isUserAuth: false})
        // the rest of your logic here
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.isLoading && <LoadingIndicator /> }
      {!this.state.isLoading && this.state.isUserAuth && <Component  {...this.props} />}
      {!this.state.isLoading && !this.state.isUserAuth && <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: this.props.location } }} />}
    );

  }
}
```

Secondly, in your `<Route>` component you should do something like:

```
<Route {...rest} render={props => (<UserAuth {...props} />)} />
```

Comment: ميرسي خالص يامحمد، أنا لسه جديد في الموضوع ففي حاجات كتير مش واضحة بالنسبالي ، كنت بتمنى يكون التعديل على نفس المثال، لان ال


`Router V4`
مختلف تماما فحسب الاقتراحات اطلب اني اعمل
`Redirect Component`
في اللينك دا
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46799951/418343 
وحضرتك بتقولي اعمل 
New component !
فانا شايف كدا الدنيا بتتعقد.

Comment: العفو يا باشا .. انا حكمل انجلش عشان لو حد ممكن يستفيد بحاجة .. قول لي بس ايه اللي مش واضح وانا افهمك (لو عارف يعني
I didn't do much. I just refactored your code. Your code needs to be refactored because as I said you can't return UI from an async callback. You're creating your component on the fly (and pass it to render property) and what I did was just gave it a name and refactored its code. Note that It's React.js way to always create reusable code through components. And btw the PrivateRoute component (on the link you posted) is a good abstraction to secure routes.